# Make a Barcode Consistent and Functional when Printing in Different Paper Sizes

Tags: jquery, css, printing, media-queries, barcode

I'm using a Jquery Plugin to  print a barcode. ( [Barcode Jquery Plugin](http://barcode-coder.com/en/barcode-jquery-plugin-201.html))

```
//Generate ID Barcode
$("#myid_info_barcode").barcode("101-03043", "code39");
```

The output is different when I print it with a "Letter" Paper Size and CR80 Card. The Bars in CR80 Card is thinner, smaller and not functional. How do I make the bar codes consistent and functional when printing in different paper sizes.

Comment: Are the bars thinner?

Comment: Did you tried set fixed size for `#myid_info_barcode`?

Comment: @DGS --> The Bars in CR80 Card is thinner and smaller. I didn't make any size distortions. It just so happen.

Comment: @MatjažMav --> How to do that?

Comment: Have you tried setting a device-width viewport meta tag?

Comment: @DGS --> Nope, I didnt even know that.

Comment: try putting `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` in the head